# Codeigniter -- _render_page() is undefined

Tags: php, codeigniter, ion-auth

I am using [ion auth with CI](https://github.com/benedmunds/CodeIgniter-Ion-Auth). What is `_render_page()`? I have been using `$this->load()` and redirect. I am getting this error:

`Fatal error: Call to undefined method Profile::_render_page()`

I didn't change the page code by ion auth so I think I have to call some library or helper but I don't know which one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

this is private method, which is used in default auth ion_auth, in your controller Profile doesnt exist this function, you probably copy only from auth (method for login/logout users) and forget for it..

**Default Auth.php**

```
function _render_page($view, $data=null, $render=false)
    {

        $this->viewdata = (empty($data)) ? $this->data: $data;

        $view_html = $this->load->view($view, $this->viewdata, $render);

        if (!$render) return $view_html;
    }
```

post here your code... now here just like that's how it's like to cook in pairs

Comment: Thanks Honza .. you were right ... i copied a part from auth and skipped this thinking render would be a php function. It works smooth now. Thanks:)

Comment: so accept my response to complete question.. such is the principle Q&A:)